# Segmentation fault when converting to Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I am in the process of updating a project to iOS 11/Swift 4. I have updated to Swift 3.2 and have a project that builds with one warning: "Conversion to Swift 4 available". So I click the warning and start the migration assistant with the option "Minimize Inference" when asked about Swift 4 @objc Inference.

The build fails quite quickly with this message: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

Stack trace:

`0  swift                    0x000000010afabdba PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010afab1f6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9ec2bb3a _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x000000010a10155a clang::ASTReader::readTypeRecord(unsigned int) + 18634
4  swift                    0x00000001085e4ff0 swift::migrator::updateCodeAndEmitRemap(swift::CompilerInstance*, swift::CompilerInvocation const&) + 960
5  swift                    0x000000010791b775 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 1925
6  swift                    0x0000000107919784 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7716
7  swift                    0x00000001078ce6a8 main + 12248
8  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff9ea1c235 start + 1`

Did anyone else have a similar issue and found a solution for it?

UPDATE: I also tried Swift 4 @objc Inference "Match Swift 3 Behavior" with the same results.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Somewhere toward the end of the giant log it showed me what method in my code it failed on. Do you have that?

Comment: Not sure, in the "program arguments" section? Basically there is two sections of massive blocks of filepaths and a stack trace in my log message. Did you fint it among all those file paths in the log?

Comment: Mine was after the migration while doing an Archive actually. I know how I fixed it, so I can probably make it happen again... But it was in the error messages of the build log for me.

Comment: Ah ok, for me the actual compiler is crashing.

Comment: Yes, so is mine. Here's what the bottom of my log says:
1. While emitting IR SIL function `@_T011InfoPanelViewC6insertyx5panel_tSo6UIViewCRbzAA04InfoD0RzlFAaH_AGXc_Tg5Tf4gn_n".
 for 'insert(panel:)' at /ViewControllers/Map/InfoPanel/InfoPanelView.swift:48:5`

Comment: Ok, I search for ".swift" and did not find any references to Swift files in the project so I probably have another issue. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I managed to solve this finally today. When I changed to recommended build settings in XCode, the compiler started crashing in normal builds and pointed me towards a function. I then managed to rewrite that function in a way that did not crash the compiler but does the same thing. After the project was building again with recommended setting, the conversion tool worked.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a Swift bug which has been filed here: https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-4646

That said, have you tried cleaning and deleting derived data?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me (as other than the segmentation fault code 11, there wasn't ANY information what was causing the error), was to **disable Whole Module optimization (set Compilation Mode to Single File under Target -> Build Settings) for all configurations.** The setting will be re-enabled for Release configs after you go through the conversion or you can re-enable it yourself.